# Android:Send the data to another Activity giving Fatal Exception

Tags: java, android, fatal-error

i have to send a details of the MainActivity.java to the Another Activity and print it there

i have created an onclick event in the mainActivity with some text into that but when i click the button the app is crashing inside the emulator and getting the exception in the logcat

MainActivity.java

```
Button buy_button = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.buy_global);
            buy_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context;    
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.coded.sandeep.Another");
                    intent.putExtra("message", "Hello From MainActivity");

                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    extras.putString("status", "Data Received!");

                    intent.putExtras(extras);

                    context.startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
```

Another.java

```
public class Another extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.another);

        // 1. get passed intent 
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        // 2. get message value from intent
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

        // 3. show message on textView 
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvMessage)).setText(message);



        // 5. get status value from bundle
        String status = bundle.getString("status");

        // 6. show status on Toast
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

LOGCAT

```
06-03 05:41:52.249: W/dalvikvm(1644): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a38ba8)
    06-03 05:41:52.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1644): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    06-03 05:41:52.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1644): Process: com.coded.sandeep, PID: 1644
    06-03 05:41:52.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1644): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.coded.sandeep.Another (has extras) }
    06-03 05:41:52.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
    06-03 05:41:52.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
    06-03 05:41:52.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
    06-03 05:41:52.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
    06-03 05:41:52.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
    06-03 05:41:52.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
    06-03 05:41:52.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at com.coded.sandeep.MusicDatabaseActivity$ImageAdapter$3.onClick(MusicDatabaseActivity.java:252)
    06-03 05:41:52.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
    06-03 05:41:52.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
    06-03 05:41:52.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    06-03 05:41:52.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    06-03 05:41:52.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    06-03 05:41:52.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    06-03 05:41:52.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-03 05:41:52.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    06-03 05:41:52.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    06-03 05:41:52.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    06-03 05:41:52.379: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there any error in the code should i change any thing

Comment: Have you declared `Another` in your manifest file? Also why do this `Intent intent = new Intent("com.coded.sandeep.Another");` instead of `Intent intent = new Intent(Another.class);`?

Comment: `context.startActivity(intent);` ... `context` is `null` in your code

Comment: no i have declared inside an image adapter as Context = context @FarhanSarwar

Comment: use getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);

Comment: **com.coded.sandeep.MusicDatabaseActivity$ImageAdapter$3.onClick(MusicDatabaseActivity.java:252)** post this code I think the problem is here

Comment: Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(),Another.class);
startActivity(in);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.coded.sandeep.Another");
```

with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Another.class);
```

MainActivity.this is the source
Another.class is the destination
Simply to say from(MainActivity) and to(Another)

Comment: Check whether we have Another Activity entry in the AndroidManifest.Intent refer androidManifest for change from one activity to another.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `Intent intent = new Intent("com.coded.sandeep.Another");` 
with

`Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Another.class);`

Creating Intents using `Intent("com.coded.sandeep.Another");` creates an intent of the type `'com.coded.sandeep.Another'`. However, since this is a custom intent and android does not know how to handle it, an exception is generated.

Edit 1 : 
Since inside the click listener, MainActivity.this instance is not available, try this :

```
Activity activity; //Instance variable
```

Inside OnCreate() :

```
activity = this;
```

Then use `Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Another.class);`

Edit 2 :

Since this is inside an adapter and your adapter does not have a context to start the activity, you can pass the context when initializing the adapter and then use that to start the activity.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Activity activity; 

    public CustomAdapter(Activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    //Now use this activity to create a new intent and start new activity inside your button click listener. 
}
```

Comment: If i change the intent then i am getting error "No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope" @Shivam Verma

Comment: Edited answer. Check Edit 1.

Comment: @ShivamVerma I dont agree with your edit I think **MainActivity.this** works just fine. I've used it many times. The problem lies somewhere else

Comment: It's because he's unable to access the context. I just gave him a way to access the context. Depends on where exactly he's creating the intent.

Answer (score 1):

try below code:-

change below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.coded.sandeep.Another");
```

**to**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Another.class);
```

Comment: If i change the intent then i am getting error "No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope" @Golu

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your Intent code like this.    Intent intent=new Intent(this,Another.class);

Comment: If i change the intent then i am getting error "No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope" @Praveen

Comment: try this     Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Another.class);

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively instead of changing your code you can change the following inside the ***manifest.xml***:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Another" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.coded.sandeep.Another" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Ya i will try and let you know bro @SMR

Comment: Same fatal exception bro @SMR